# Jquery Hide and show with Radio button

Tags: jquery

I have 2 radio button inputs

```
<input type="radio" name="isBooking" value="false" id="isNotBooking" checked/>
<input type="radio" name="isBooking" value="true" id="isBooking" />

<input type="text" id="bookingForm" />
```

What i want is when the radio button with ID = isNotBooking is checked, the bookingForm will be hidden, if radio button with ID = isBooking is checked, the bookingForm will be shown.

I try this code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("#isNotBooking").is(':checked')) {
    $("#bookingForm").hide();
  } 

  if ($("#isBooking").is(':checked')) {
    $("#bookingForm").show();
  }
});
```

This code only works for one time after the page finish loading (its hidden since i set the ID isNotBooking attribute "Checked"), after that, no matter which one i check, it won't hide or show, why ?

Comment: you need add click event

Comment: I don't want to use click event, because if the default is radio button with IsBooking ID, it will not shown. (Since user not click on it, its already default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides checking RadioButtons on page load, you have to attach `.change()` event also with RadioButtons as shown :-

```
$('input:radio[name=isBooking]').on('change',function(){
   if(this.checked && this.id == "isNotBooking"){
       $("#bookingForm").hide();
   }
   else if(this.checked && this.id == "isBooking"){
       $("#bookingForm").show();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

#### View Demo [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ypwm32jx/1/)

#### jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#bookingForm").hide();
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).attr("id")=="isNotBooking"){
            $("#bookingForm").hide();
        }
        if($(this).attr("id")=="isBooking"){
            $("#bookingForm").show();
        }
    });
});
```

#### HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="isBooking" value="false" id="isNotBooking" checked/>
<input type="radio" name="isBooking" value="true" id="isBooking" />

<input type="text" id="bookingForm" />
```